# C# Continue to show TaskBar progress until window has focus

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar

I have a WPF app with a routine which runs in a thread and displays progress in the taskbar icon. When the task is finished, if the window is hidden, I'd like to continue to show the task bar state until the window has focus and then set it to none. How can I achieve this?

```
this.taskBarItem.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
this.taskBarItem.ProgressValue = 0.0;

await Task.Run(() => DoWork();

this.taskBarItem.ProgressValue = 1.0;
while (!System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.IsActive)
{
    // Pause until Window has focus
}
this.taskBarItem.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.None;
```

Comment: Window has an activated event. You can subscribe to that and do stuff.  Probably best then un-subscribing your handler.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to C#. Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: In your xaml you have a Window tag. Inside that type Activated= and accept the suggested new event. In code behind you will now have an event handler stub you can put code into. You need some name for your taskbaritem so you can reference it so give it a Name= or x:Name =.  You can then tell that control to do whatever you like. Such as set it's state to none. If  you want to hook and unhook that eventhandler you can do this.Activated += yourhandler and then this.Activated -= yourhandler. I recommend some reading around wpf event handlers.